# rviz exception while loading: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException)

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have been using rviz with no problems up until recently where upon using "rosrun rviz rviz" it begins loading and then promptly crashes and shuts down:

```
rosrun rviz rviz

INFO [1311775709.546537962]: Loading general config from [/home/ros/.rviz/config]

INFO [1311775709.546746875]: Loading display config from [/home/ros/.rviz/display_config]

ERROR [1311775712.566807201]: Caught exception while loading: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Cannot create GL vertex buffer in GLHardwareVertexBuffer::GLHardwareVertexBuffer at /code/ros/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-1/RenderSystems/GL/src/OgreGLHardwareVertexBuffer.cpp (line 46)
Segmentation fault
```

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding it, but to no avail. I also haven't (knowingly) modified any files that are involved with rviz.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10744/rviz-exception-while-loading:-ogre-exception(7:internalerrorexception)/) by [rohan_k](https://answers.ros.org/users/856/rohan_k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2011-07-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bram van de Klundert](https://answers.ros.org/users/392/bram-van-de-klundert/) on 2011-07-27**:
did the pc where you get that error on have c-turtle installed on it (before diamondback)? a simular error happend for me, i manged to get it running by removing the c-turtle version and reinstalling the diamondback one

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-27**:
What do you get in glxinfo? Did you recently (re-)install graphics drivers or a system update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

no activity in > 1 month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0